# regex to ignore string ends with specific pattern

Tags: regex, regex-look-ahead

I am trying to write regex which should ignore any string ends with _numbers like (_1234)

like below

```
abc_def_1234 - should not match
abc_fgh - match
abc_ghj -  match
abc_ijk_2345 - not match
```

I am trying to use lookahead regex like below, but it's matching everything. Can someone please help me how I can achieve this?

```
\w+(?!_\d+)
```

Comment: please explain why `abc_fgh` should match but `abc_ghj` should not match. They look like they are examples of the same type of input to me.

Comment: @Bohemian sorry that was a typo, edited my post

Comment: Tip: `\w` is equal to: `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` so it also matches digits and underscores - not what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Match words separated by underscores, but use a negative look ahead to exclude input that has the unwanted tail:

```
^(?!.*_\d+$)\w+(?<!_)$
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/tGrPjcOLhpH0Gu).

The last look behind (which you can remove) is there to require that the last char is not an underscore - ie that the input is AFAICT well formed.

Comment: Underscore is part of `\w` so the last parantese is not necessary.

Comment: @PoulBak Good point. I’ve corrected that to keep my original intent.